# notification on data waiting to be read on serial link

Tags: c, serial-port, glib

I try to add to my g_main_loop a new source that is a file descriptor on a serial line peripheric.

I try this code :

```
GError* error;
GIOChannel* channel;
channel=g_io_channel_unix_new(fd_serial_line_dev);
g_io_add_watch(channel, G_IO_IN, cb_1, NULL);
g_io_channel_set_close_on_unref(channel, TRUE);
g_io_channel_set_encoding(channel, NULL, &error);
g_io_channel_set_buffered(channel, FALSE);
```

The callback is :

```
gboolean cb_1 (GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
  gchar** line=NULL;
  GIOStatus status;
  GError* error;

  printf("cb\n");

  status=g_io_channel_read_line(source, line, NULL, NULL, &error);

  if(G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL == status)
  {
    printf("callback : data : %s\n", *line);
    g_free(*line);
    //g_io_channel_seek_position(source, 0, G_SEEK_CUR, NULL);
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

When I send data on the serial line, I obtain an infinite loop that call cb_1 each time.

I don't see where is my mistake, I expected that a read within file descriptor of the serial line will be suffisant to stop call to the callback during the next g main loop iteration...

Comment: From what I understand you should be returning false on an error to close the channel.

Comment: I try and with this solution callback will never be called, even if a new caracter is comming. For me, returning FALSE is usefull if the event source should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, GLib g_io_add_watch method adds your file descriptor to poll(). poll on /dev files is not same as sockets descriptors or normal files. Check struct fops structure in your driver to know whether poll operation is supported by your driver or not. Usually they do support unless you are using some custom driver. Also cross check your code with any other /dev file.

Check whether the status returned from g_io_channel_read_line in the callback is G_IO_STATUS_AGAIN which mean resource is temporarily unavailable; so, a event happened on your file descriptor but there is no immediate data available to read from the driver buffers.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `g_io_channel_unref(channel)` immediatley after g_io_add_watch. Then in your callback add

```
if(G_IO_STATUS_EOF == status)
 return FALSE;
```

> g_io_channel_*_new() returns a GIOChannel
>   object with a reference count of one.  g_io_add_watch() adds a further
>   reference count - if you decrement it by 1, the callback will be
>   disconnected and the relevant GSource object removed when the callback
>   returns FALSE, which it should do when it detects end-of-file, or if
>   you call g_source_remove() on the return value of g_io_add_watch()